# Node , SSh2 Server waiting for input

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

I am currently building a Web based SSH client. I am using node and SSH2 module to connect to Linux machine . The issue is trying to identify when the server is waiting for a response from the client say "sudo" .

```js
 this.onWsMessage = function(packet) {
    log('Message Received from ');
    if (cmd != '') {
      log('----------------------------------------->' + cmd);
      source[this.getId()].sshStream.write(cmd + '\n');
    }

  };

 var client = clients[cid];
sshClient
  .on('ready', function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED');
    sshClient.shell({pty: true}, function(err, stream) {
      _shellHandler(err, stream, client);
    });
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('ERROR', err);
  })
  .connect(serverInfo);
  }

function _shellHandler(err, stream, client) {
source[client.getId()].sshStream = stream;
stream
  .on('close', function() {
    log('ssh connection close');
    //sshClient.end();
    this._client.end();
  })
  .on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(stream);
    var msg = data.toString().replace(msgPattern, '');
    this.sendUTF(msg, 'ssh');

  }.bind(client));


  }
```

I have been going through the documentation and i was unable to identify any event that trigger as a result.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. Basically you have to either buffer stream output and continually search that buffer for expected (sudo) prompts or use a module like [`streamsearch`](https://github.com/mscdex/streamsearch) to search the stream for a particular string without explicitly buffering and continual searching.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I think watching for the default linux prompt in the response may be a way to detect waits on the server.   Very useful module BTW